# abs visible but there arent horizontal lines

Tags: abdominals

Hello my abs are seemed but I think I haven't created good.What I mean if you look me you can see that my abs are visible but I haven't created horizontal lines.I have the vertical between that separates 3abs and the 3abs from the other side.How to do horizontal  lines in my abs.Additional slope my abs seemed

Comment: Burn more fat to get more definition.

Comment: If I do more often abs workout I will see faster results?I mean I will burn more fat by that?

Comment: No. Ab workouts aren't meant to burn belly fat. You need to burn fat either by cardio, or by managing your diet.

Comment: I  google cardio but I can't understand what it is.Could you tell me :)

Comment: Running, rowing, biking etc.

Comment: What Alec says is basically burning fat helps show the muscles while strength/resistance training help build muscles. If you build but cannot show because there is fat covering them, building more won't help as much as dieting more. Diet & nutrition along with proper rest/sleep and hydration play a major role in body fat control. Don't neglect diet. What he means by cardiovascular is basically aerobic and endurance workouts that keeps your heart rate between 60-85% of its max over a longer period. They are longer steady workout such as running, bicycling, elliptical machines, etc...

Comment: Also, what creates the "lines" in your abdominals is the connective tissue attached to the rectus abdominus sheet of muscle. You may not have as many divisions as other people have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the way your abs look is purely genetics. If there isn't a big separation between your abs, you'll never really be able to see it properly, this is why some people have a 4 pack, some have 6, some have 8.

**That being said, you probably have to lose a bit more fat.**

You don't need to do cardio to burn fat if you don't want to. If you keep your diet in check, doing compound movements is enough. They burn a lot of calories as well as build muscle.

Doing squats and deadlifts will also be working your core, so you'd be losing fat and gaining core strength.

Comment: There is something to be said for directly working abdominals to promote targeted growth, especially if they are not clearly defined at low bodyfat percentages.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I'm not saying he shouldn't workout his abs, he's already doing that.